# str object is not callable in django python code

Tags: python, string

I keep getting the error that str object is not callable. my line of code is pasted below... can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

random = str(uuid.uuid4().hex().upper()[0:6])

Comment: if you have such kind of problems it's best to decompose the line in question and you will normally find the error. or have a clearer understanding.

example line1: `v = uuid.uuid4()`  line 2: `v = v.hex()`  line 3: `v = v.upper()` line 4: v = v[0:6]`  ; line 5 : `random = str(v)`

What's also important is to show us the import line, that you were using for uuid.

Answer (score 1):

change `hex()` to `hex`. `.hex` is a property, not a function, and it already returns a string.